# Writing SQL runtime/syntax errors to a text file

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, runtime-error

I want to generate a text file if there are syntax or runtime errors in a SQL stored procedure.
For example, I want to create a text file with this information when the procedure is called and if the following error is generated:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure sp_LoadKAD_UAT, Line 94 [Batch Start Line 94]
> Error converting data type varchar to float.

I am not using any other front-end tools. I need the solution in SQL server.
I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2017

I have done research on TRY and catch blocks and @@Error but I have not got the solution yet.

Comment: You can get the error in a catch block from `error_message()` You can insert this into a logging table from which you can query or export the data. If you really must do it all in sql server there are scripts for utility functions to write to a file using `scripting.filesystemobject`.

Comment: Use try_convert( float, YourColumn )   ... this will return NULL if the conversion fails rather than throwing an error.    Now, if you want to see the trouble rows   Select * from YourTable Where try_convert( float, YourColumn ) is NULL and YourColumn is not NULL

Answer (score 0):

Using Try Catch block you can handle the error message and insert into any Temporary table.

```
Declare @Catcherror as Table (Errornumber int, Errormessage varchar(100))

BEGIN TRY 
    Declare @num1 as int=1, @num2 as int = 0, @result as int
    set @result= @num1/@num2

end TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    insert into @Catcherror (Errornumber, Errormessage)
    Select ERROR_NUMBER() as Errornumber, ERROR_MESSAGE() as Errormessage
end CATCH

Select * from @Catcherror
```